# Setting the Thumb and progress dialog color in Android using Yahoo library for RangeSeekBar

Tags: android, colors, rangeseekbar

I am not able to provide color of my choice to Thumb and progress dialog using "com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.util.rangeseekbar:rangeseekbar-library:0.1.0" library.

Below are the ways which I have tried:

1. rangeseekBar.setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
2. rangeseekBar.setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
3. rangeseekBar.setAccessibilityLiveRegion(Color.RED);
4. rangeseekBar.setColorFilter(Color.RED);

But no luck. Anyone please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

In library SeekBar [color](https://github.com/yahoo/android-range-seek-bar/blob/master/rangeseekbar/src/main/java/com/yahoo/mobile/client/android/util/rangeseekbar/RangeSeekBar.java) define  as

```
public static final int DEFAULT_COLOR = Color.argb(0xFF, 0x33, 0xB5, 0xE5);
```

so use

```
  RangeSeekBar.DEFAULT_COLOR = Color.argb(0xFF, 0x33, 0xB5, 0xE5);// change your custom color value.
```

Comment: "DEFAULT_COLOR" variable is declared as "final" in the library, so its not allowing me to change the color of my choice.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563652/static-final-variable-in-java

Comment: im not able to change the color