# How can I set Constant?

Tags: java

```
public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

         if(args.length < 2) {
             System.err.println("Error !!");
             System.exit(1);    
        }
          float distance = Float.parseFloat(args[0]);
          float time = Float.parseFloat(args[1]);

          System.out.print("Velocity = " );
          System.out.print(distance / time);
          System.out.print(" m/s ");
        }   
}
```

How can I make variables constant?
Constant **distance = 10**;
Constant **time = 5**;

Thank Everyone!

Comment: Add `final` to the variable declaration: `final float distance = ...`

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to achieve. As it stands, the question is rather cryptic.

Comment: @NPE I actually think it is quite clear what the OP is asking. What's cryptic about it?

Comment: if you're using the constants in static methods, also add the reserved word static: final static float distance = 10; See the answer above.

Comment: @AliAlamiri: Well I certainly don't understand "How do I need to set constants?" - what do you understand by that question?

Comment: Wow that was a fast closure. 4 minutes? Give the guy a chance to explain!

Comment: @JonSkeet It could be a problem that his English is not very good, and he couldn't express the question of "How do I make variables constant" in a better way.

Comment: @Boann - Agreed, it's actually a bit harsh.  sorry op

Comment: The question definitely doesn't need to be closed.

Comment: @AliAlamiri: Yes, I'm sure it's that his English isn't very good. But that doesn't make it any clearer. What is the "No change source code" bit about? Given that the code already prints the distance and time, what's really left to change? *Why* does the OP want constants?

Comment: @AliAlamiri: Until the OP edits it to actually make it a *clear* question, I completely agree with it being closed as "not a real question".

Answer (score 4):

```
final float distance = Float.parseFloat(args[0]);
final float time = Float.parseFloat(args[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

YOu can try something liek this:-

```
public static final int x= 11;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just declare them.

```
  public class Test2 {
        public static final float distance = 10;
        public static final float time = 5;
        public static void main(String[] args) {

             if(args.length < 2) {
                 System.err.println("Error !!");
                 System.exit(1);    
            }
              float distance = Float.parseFloat(args[0]);
              float time = Float.parseFloat(args[1]);

              System.out.print("Velocity = " );
              System.out.print(distance / time);
              System.out.print(" m/s ");
            }   
    }
```

Comment: **// No change source code .**  :)

Comment: Look close at the beginning my friend: public static final float distance = 10;
        public static final float time = 5;

Comment: yes, you changed the source codes. :D the weird requirement... :)

Comment: oh, btw, I am not the downvoter...:)

Answer (score 0):

This is done using the `final` keyword

```
public static final int distance = 10
```

then you can just use the `distance` wherever you need 10 ( [src](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/Varconstltr.shtml) )

also see: [private final static attribute vs private final attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415955/private-final-static-attribute-vs-private-final-attribute)

Comment: It's `final` not `FINAL`.

Comment: You can't declare `public` nor `static` variables inside a method.