# Where are static final variables used in java?

Tags: java, final, static-members

I am studying java and wanted to know what's the usage of `static final` variables in application designing. Please provide some examples too.

Comment: Well, constants, mostly...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415955/private-final-static-attribute-vs-private-final-attribute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uses of a `static final` variable :

1. To define a compile time constant value. e.g : The `Integer` class defines a constant called `MIN_VALUE` as :  `public static final int  MIN_VALUE = 0x80000000;`
2. To create a non modifiable reference that can be accessed globally : E.g The [Singleton](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=3) pattern using a `public static final` reference.

When you mark a variable defined in a class as `static`, it is shared across all the instances of a `class`. When you mark a variable in a class as `final`, it can only be initialized once either on the same line as the declaration of the variable or in the constructor of the class. Putting both together, a member `static final` variable is shared across all instances of a `class`, must be initialized where it is declared, and cannot be modified once declared.

Answer (score 1):

`final` means the reference can't be changed once it's set. `static` means the variable belongs to a **class**, not a specific **instance**. This combination of modifiers, especially when used on a primitive or an immutable class (such as `String`) are often used to represent constants. A classic example would be [`java.io.File.separtorChar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separatorChar).

Answer (score 0):

You can define constants like

```
public static final String LANGUAGE = "JAVA"
```

Comment: There is a significant typo in there :)